# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have shape (34,) but got array with shape (36,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, image-processing, lstm

I've trained a TPU with Keras for Image Captioning. I'm getting an error when I ran:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
def generateCaption(photo):

  in_text = START
  for i in range(max_length):
    sequence = [wordtoidx[w] for w in in_text.split() if w in wordtoidx]
    sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_length)

    yhat = caption_model.predict([photo,sequence], verbose=0)
    yhat = np.argmax(yhat)

    word = idxtoword[yhat]
    in_text += ' ' + word

    if word == STOP:
      break

    final = in_text.split()
    final = final[1:-1]
    final = ' '.join(final)

    return final


for z in range(10):
  pic = list(encoding_test.keys())[z]
  image = encoding_test[pic].reshape((1,OUTPUT_DIM))

  print(os.path.join(root_captioning,'/content/drive/My Drive/ImageCaptioning/Flicker8k Dataset', pic))
  x = plt.imread(os.path.join(root_captioning,'/content/drive/My Drive/ImageCaptioning/Flicker8k Dataset', pic))

  plt.imshow(x)
  plt.show()

  print("Caption:",generateCaption(image))
  print("_____________________________________")
```

Error in line: `print("Caption:",generateCaption(image))`
I tried different reshaping options an also tried to remove the reshape function but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when i was trying to train networks, so it has probably do with the **LSTM**. In this specific case the model complains because the **third layer** has a dimension mismatch. you can try checking if the training images have the same dimensions as the one you're using here, or checking the layer's parameters.

Comment: Toy're welcome =) can you please mark the answer as correct? Thanks!